# itext7 HTML to PDF ignores column widths

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm using iText7's pdfHtml add-on to convert an HTML table into a PDF. However I cannot get it to obey the defined column widths.

I'm using the `HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument` to convert my HTML into a PDF.

This is my table:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gray-header {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 700px;">
  <thead>
    <tr class="gray-header">
      <th rowspan="2" style="width: 50px;">A</th>
      <th rowspan="2" style="width: 250px;">B</th>
      <th colspan="4" style="width: 400px;">COLSPAN</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gray-header">
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>G</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the table in the PDF

[image]

The columns A and B are the same width. B should be 5 times larger then A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround is to specify column width definitions in `<col>` tags located in `<colgroup>`:

```html
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 700px;">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 50px;"/>
    <col style="width: 250px;"/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
  <tr class="gray-header">
    <th rowspan="2">A</th>
    <th rowspan="2">B</th>
    <th colspan="4">COLSPAN</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gray-header">
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Visual PDF result for the table structure above:

[image: result]